# Removing brackets from velocity template (xml escaping)

Tags: escaping, velocity, apache-velocity, velocity-template-language

I am new to velocity template. 
I am using velocity template to parse the data in xml format.
Using below code to fetch userId: 
$esc.xml("$!userDetails.userId).replaceAll("&#[0-9a-fA-F]+;","")

Generated output: [ABC123]
Excepted output: ABC123

Can someone please help me here. Also, I googled for apache velocity wiki but didn't find one. 
Also, it would be better if provide some wiki to fetch more information.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape [] characters which are regular expression keywords

```
.replaceAll("&#\[0-9a-fA-F\]+;","")
```